# start time of day with datetime string

Tags: t-sql

I believe that this is the start datetime of January the first 2012 expresses as a string/nvarchar:

```
SELECT CAST('2012-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)
```

It shows:

```
2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

If I do:

```
DECLARE @CutOffDateTime DATETIME
SELECT @CutOffDateTime = CAST('2012-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)
PRINT @CutOffDateTime
```

It shows:

```
Jan  1 2012 12:00AM
```

which IMHO is the midday of January the first 2012. Is the above string correct? Why does print change the actual time?

Comment: 1200AM is midnight https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101128200214AAdjxoT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is not always clear what times "12:00 a.m." and "12:00 p.m."
>   denote. From the Latin words meridies (midday), ante (before) and post
>   (after), the term ante meridiem (a.m.) means before midday and post
>   meridiem (p.m.) means after midday. Since strictly speaking "noon"
>   (midday) is neither before nor after itself, the terms a.m. and p.m.
>   do not apply.[16] However, since 12:01 p.m. is after noon, it is
>   common to extend this usage for 12:00 p.m. to denote noon. **That leaves
>   12:00 a.m. to be used for midnight at the beginning of the day**,
>   continuing to 12:01 a.m. that same day.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock

Formatting your datetime to a 24H clock shows the time as 00:00

```
DECLARE @CutOffDateTime DATETIME
SELECT @CutOffDateTime = CAST('2012-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)
PRINT @CutOffDateTime 
PRINT convert(varchar, @CutOffDateTime, 126)
```

Output

```
Jan  1 2012 12:00AM
2012-01-01T00:00:00
```

This is one of the main reasons I prefer the 24 hour clock, less confusion.

..further reading here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31119/how-to-avoid-1200-am-midnight-noon-confusion-in-a-time-input-field

Comment: Thanks - clear as mud (-: (makes sense though with all your references)